# Azure Machine Learning notebooks: ModuleNotFound error

Tags: torch, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-notebooks

I'm working through a Python exercise using Azure Machine Learning notebooks. I'm unable to `import torch` even after `!pip install torch`.

Notebook says `Requirement already satisfied`, then errors out with:

```
!pip install torch

import torch

data = torch.tensor(encode(text), dtype=torch.long)
print(data.shape, data.dtype)
print(data[:100])

4 sec

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
Requirement already satisfied: torch in /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from torch) (4.4.0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [22], in <cell line: 4>()
      1 # Encode the entire dataset and store it into a torch.Tensor
      3 get_ipython().system('pip install torch')
----> 4 import torch
      5 data = torch.tensor(encode(text), dtype=torch.long)
      6 print(data.shape, data.dtype)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

I opened up a terminal in Azure ML Studio and tried `pip install torch` too, same `Requirement already satisfied` message showed.

How do I get `torch` (and any other Python modules where this occurs) working in AML notebooks?

Comment: I'm really hoping someone can assist. I'm attempting to use AML notebooks as a GCollab replacement.  I don't want to lose momentum on this tutorial!

Answer (score 4):

The issue was lined out in the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-run-jupyter-notebooks#manage-packages). Don't use `!pip` within the notebook. Instead use `%pip`.

Answer (score 2):

I've found creating environments and installing packages through the terminal to be a much more reliable experience than doing it from an AML notebook.

I suggest using one of the provided terminals (either the one available in the compute instance's details, or the one available in JupyterLab) to create a new conda environment which you can customize to your liking.

Something like:

```bash
conda create -n my_tutorial python=3.10

conda activate my_tutorial

pip install --user ipykernel

python -m ipykernel install --user --name=my_tutorial

# Do a complete install of PyTorch, take a look at the available versions here https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/
conda install pytorch=1.13 torchvision=0.14 torchaudio=0.13 pytorch-cuda=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia -y
```

Afterwards, just make sure your notebooks use the `my_tutorial` kernel and you should be good to go. Whenever you want to `pip install` something new, just go back to the terminal, activate your kernel, and install the thing, then it should be available in your notebooks as well.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I actually did use the terminal as well. I get the "Requirement already satisfied" message when running `pip install torch` using the Workspace terminal. But as you can see, the Notebook can't import torch.

Comment: Disregard. I figured it out. I'm not supposed to use `!pip` but rather `%pip`.