# Does Azure Machine Learning charge for Compute Instances even when they are stopped?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I created a new Azure Machine Learning Workspace and Compute Instance to work through some Python ML tutorials. I was stuck on [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75154808/azure-machine-learning-notebooks-modulenotfound-error) for a few days. While I was waiting for assistance, I stopped the compute instance.

Looking through the Cost Analysis for this Resource Group, it looks like I'm being charged even though the Compute Instance has been stopped for a few days.

Is there a pay-as-you-go version of AML Compute Instance so I don't get charged when the instance is turned off?

---

**EDIT**:

Hm. It looks like the bulk of the cost is coming from a Load Balancer and Storage not the Compute Instance (assuming this is the "VM" shown). The Compute Instance was stopped in the AML Studio.

[image]
[image]

Its unclear to me which Azure Resource the Load Balancer represents.

[image]

Also the only Storage account in this Resource Group has 3 empty Containers...

[image]

Maybe these costs were associated with setting up the AML Workspace?

Comment: If you stop the compute VM instance it should not incur any cost. However, it should be stopped from the portal (or via script). Shutting off the VM does not help. Other services if any will continue to be charged if provisioned.

Comment: @Yogi, edited the original post. Further thoughts?

Comment: Yes it's because of other components created with the workspace as you see in the cost analysis. For individual services and components, you can see the pricing for them in Azure pricing and optimize them appropriately.

Comment: Hm...I've definitely stopped the Compute Instance but the costs keep increasing beyond my hourly usage. I've been using a Notebook on the Compute Instance for maybe 1-3hrs a day. I've got the cheapest instance ($0.06/hr.) as I'm just working through tutorials and wanted to experiment with AML service.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. As seen in the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-workspace#sub-resources), there is a Load Balancer resource that is provisioned as part of the AML Workspace. This resource is not visible in the Resource Group (which was throwing me off). It appears to accumulate cost even with the Compute Resource turned off.